# onLayout is triggered multiple times react native

Tags: layout, redux, react-native

This is my code:

```
<View onLayout={(event) => {
    console.log('Inside');
    this.props.setDropZoneValue(event.nativeEvent.layout);
}}
style={styles.borderView}>
......
</View>
```

On android this is coming in many times here and it is supposed to enter only 1 time. Works perfect on ios.

I'm working on react with redux

The line:

`This.props.setDropZoneValue(event.nativeEvent.layout);`

It is an action that modifies the reducer and therefore causes the view to be rendered again and re-enters the onLayout and is resulting in an infinite loop

**Anyone know any reason for this to happen only on android?**

Comment: Simple solution would be setting up a variable if the onLayout event is already fired or not and checking it before running the function. But you should also figure  out why it is rerunning the onLayout event. My solution is really temporary.

Comment: hi @BünyaminBennyGenel, yes, Right now that's my temporary solution, but if my boss sees that code like that, he kills me. XD

Comment: Did you ever find out a solution to this?

Comment: Plus one. In my case, the onLayout is called four times, each with different heights